# Swift, Xcode: Changing UIButton Background and Text on Click

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to change the background and text of the button on click, I tried several SO solutions but they haven't worked, you can see what I tried in my project:
https://github.com/jzhang172/modalTest

I tried debugging it by putting a simple print statement and it looks like it doesn't ever go to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

1) Create an IBAction from your UIButton and also an IBOutlet called `button`.

EDIT: As per your request (How to trigger the even when the button is TOUCHED, not RELEASED?):

[image]

2) Do this:

```
@IBAction func changes (sender: UIButton) {

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    button.setTitle("Button Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, however it only shows the background as blue when I release the mouse on it, is there a way to do it when I click on it?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted, I get this error though after I click it and it changes to gray: 2016-05-15 16:18:15.708 ModalTest3[18234:2955837] -[ModalTest3.helpViewController buttonChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9238abed0
2016-05-15 16:18:15.712 ModalTest3[18234:2955837] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ModalTest3.helpViewController buttonChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9238abed0'

Comment: @Snorlax Nothing to do with my answer :/ This must have something to do with storyboard settings or some other code :)

Comment: If anyone is looking here and gets the same error, the reason for my error was that I had extra functions in my button....right click on the button and remove functions/outlets you aren't using

Comment: @Snorlax  Indeed, always remember to clean up your IBActions and IBOutlets !

Answer (score 4):

UIButton's have a method for setting the title color. So if you had a UIButton IBOutlet named myBtn:

```
myBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
```

and to change the text of the button on touch:

```
myBtn.setTitle("This button was touched", forState: .Highlighted)
```

As far as setting the background color, you could add an extension for your UIButton which allows you to do this:

```
extension UIButton {
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forUIControlState state: UIControlState) {
        self.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color), forState: state)
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
myBtn.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forUIControlState: .Highlighted)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your UIButton @IBOutlet `closePop` is hooked up to a single @IBAction of the exact same name (`closePop()`). That `closePop()` IBAction ONLY dismisses the helpViewController - it doesn't do anything about the text or button color.

Your other @IBAction function `like`, in which you try to set the color & print "Is this even working?", is not hooked up to the button, and is never called.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!