# How does this code change a button's background color when clicked?

Tags: ios, property-observer

The following code gotten from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted) post supposedly changes a button's color when it is pressed.

```
  override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if highlighted {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            } else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I was wondering what the variable "highlighted" would corrospond too?

If I programatically added a button to my view like this:

```
let exampleButton = UIButton()
self.view.addSubview(exampleButton)
//Set constraints,title-text,etc...
```

How would I get this to work with `exampleButton`?

Comment: `exampleButton.highlighted = true` ?

Comment: I answered a similar question a few weeks back. This link will give you the answer you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37218041/4660602